# send a email with C# via default email application (thunderbird, Outlook)

Tags: c#, winforms, email

So i am looking for something just like the mailto function in html but for C#. I have tried to use the mailmessage object in C# but it would provide me with a error for unknown reasons. I also do not want to use the smtp method because i want a compose window to open in outlook or whatever your default email application is

Comment: Show us what you have tried. What error did you get?

Comment: do a google search on `C# and mailto`

Comment: This page has a lot of `RELATED` links as well if you just take the time to browse the page towards the bottom right hand side of this current page..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("mailto:test@test.com?subject=Hello&body=This%20is%20a%20test");
```